# What's wrong with the scala code in Play Framework with Morphia?

Tags: scala, playframework

I wrote the following code in Play Framework 2.2 with Scala.

```
def findContainerByUID(uid: String): UserToolbar = {
    var userToolbar = MorphiaHelper
       .getDataStore().find(UserToolbar.getClass(), "uid", uid).get()

    userToolbar.asInstanceOf[UserToolbar]
}
```

However, when i try to compile, i got the following error.

ow can getCommonSuperclass() do its job if different class symbols get the same bytecode-level internal name:xxxxxx

What is the problem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843769/getting-how-can-getcommonsuperclass-do-its-job-if-different-class-symbols-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `UserToolbar.getClass()` with `classOf[UserToolbar]`. `UserToolbar.getClass()` returns the class of the `UserToolbar` companion object, not the class `UserToolbar` itself.